# Poster HTML inside a web page

Tags: html, landing-page, advertisement

There's a type of web layout called *Poster HTML*, quite interesting for designers (not *digital poster* which is another thing for static advertising displays). They are usually very graphic, without anything typical of a website such as menus or buttons, with few or only one link that occupies the entire HTML and a scroll to see it completely.

This link [peppasauce.love](https://www.peppasauce.love/) is a very clear and interesting example.

The drawback I see is that it's a single element reached through a link, an HTML mail, or a QR code.

I've been trying for a while to find a commercial way to offer this to some clients. I'm captivated by the idea and the possibilities in terms of design, but I cannot find a practical way to offer it. Like an advertisement within the client's website, something dynamic and immediate that can be seen without clicking anywhere or scanning a QR.

What comes to mind is a landing page on a website with a duration time, like a modal window with a delay, but instead of being a frame within a web page, it should be the entire page for a period of time. Once it has disappeared, a link can be placed on the web page itself to see it again.

Does this exist? Does it have a technical name? Any other idea or alternative?

Comment: Note that making content appear and disappear based a delay rather than explicit user action is bad for usability and accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting concept. I don't see a name for this beyond "full page scrolling site" or "one page scrolling site".

[Onepagelove.com](https://onepagelove.com/) has several [inspirational applications](https://onepagelove.com/inspiration) (admittedly not as cool as peppasauce). A theme amongst them is that **they give the user a reason to keep scrolling** - they're educating the user, providing a unique way to tell a story, providing a delightful way for the user to experience a holiday greeting, etc.

Perhaps by giving the user something very valuable in exchange for engaging with the content and scrolling all the way to the end, inbound campaigns through email/social/QR could work.

Comment: This is a pretty cool one found under Long Form Journalism: https://www.kalso.com/?ref=onepagelove

Comment: Very nice, for me (or for my clients), only the bottom part with the products would work. A good example to consider, something practical for online stores.